# Is $\int_x^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} < \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, exponential-function

While solving a problem in real analysis, I got stuck. I need to prove $$\int_x^{\infty}e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt <  \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $$

Clearly I have to use some kind of inequality, but cant figure out how to proceed further.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611724/showing-that-int-x-infty-frac1u2e-u2-2du-frac1xe-x2-2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

$$e^{-t^2/2} = \frac{t}{t}e^{-t^2/2} < \frac{t}{x}e^{-t^2/2}$$

for $t > x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Seems easier now.

Answer (score 5):

This is (almost) the Gaussian Tail inequality. The proof can be found on this [page](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=stat705/Lecture2.pdf).

The rest of contains many similar inequalities which can also be of interest. For example, you could also use Markov's inequality to prove it in a line or two.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for the additional reference.